# how to add a date and time from Edittext to date picker and timepicker?

Tags: android

my fragment.java is

```
    public class myFragment1 extends Fragment {
        private EditText ettime,etdate;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.create_event_step2, container, false);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);


        ettime = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.ettime);
        etdate = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.etdate);



        etdate.setOnClickListener(dateDialog());
        ettime.setOnClickListener(timeDialog());
        return view;
}


    private View.OnClickListener  timeDialog() {
        return new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final Dialog gameTypes = new Dialog(getActivity(), android.R.style.Theme_DeviceDefault_Dialog);
                gameTypes.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                gameTypes.setContentView(R.layout.time_popup_layout);
                gameTypes.show();
                TimePicker tmPk1= (TimePicker) gameTypes.findViewById(R.id.fromtimePicker);
                tmPk1.setOnTimeChangedListener(timeChanged());
            //    TimePicker tmPk2= (TimePicker) gameTypes.findViewById(R.id.totimePicker);
            //    tmPk2.setOnTimeChangedListener(timeChanged(tmPk2, "to"));

            }
        };
    }


    private TimePicker.OnTimeChangedListener timeChanged() {
        return new TimePicker.OnTimeChangedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTimeChanged(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                String min=(String.valueOf(minute).length()==1?
                        "0"+String.valueOf(minute):String.valueOf(minute));
                step2.put("STime", hourOfDay + ":" + min);
                ettime.setText(hourOfDay + ":" + min);
              //  if (fr.equals("from")) from=hourOfDay+""+minute;
              //  if (fr.equals("to")) to=hourOfDay+""+minute;

            }
        };
    }

    private View.OnClickListener dateDialog() {
    return new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final Dialog gameTypes = new Dialog(getActivity(),android.R.style.Theme_DeviceDefault_Dialog);
            gameTypes.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            gameTypes.setContentView(R.layout.date_popup_layout);
            gameTypes.show();
            DatePicker dpk1= (DatePicker) gameTypes.findViewById(R.id.datepk1);
          //  dpk1.updateDate(Calendar.YEAR,Calendar.MONTH,Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();
            dpk1.init(
                    today.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                    today.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                    today.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH),
                    new DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view,
                                                  int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                            step2.put("GmDate", year + "-" + (monthOfYear + 1) + "-" + dayOfMonth);
                            etdate.setText(year + "-" + (monthOfYear + 1) + "-" + dayOfMonth);
                        }
                    });

        }
    };
    }
```

what i want is that when i click on edit text

if there's no data in the time edit text ..

the time picker show the time now

else
the time picker show the time is on the edit text

and

if there's no data in the date edit text ..

the datepicker show the date now

else
the date picker show the date is on the edit text

Answer (score 0):

Have a custom DialogBuilder class since you'll have more than one dialog usage in your code.

Once you click on `time` or `datepicker` edittext send either `null` or edittext content to the dialog.

If data is null show a picker with `current time` or `today's date`,
else show a picker with predefined data (passed to the dialog when called).

Answer (score 0):

The trick to this is disabling your `EditText`s so that the keyboard does not open when they gain focus. You may also want to disable focus on them.

You can do this in XML like this

```
<EditText
    ...
    android:enabled="false"
    android:focusable="false"
    />
```

Or in code after you have a reference

```
ettime.setEnabled(false);
ettime.setFocusable(false);
```

You need to add a little logic to your [`OnClickListeners`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html) to set the time to the current time if there is no time already entered. For example:

```
EditText editText = (EditText) v;
if (editText.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
    // set current time
} else {
    // open dialog
}
```

To format the date or time from a [`Date`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Date.html) or [`Calendar`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html) object to a human readable form, try using [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

For the date and time picker, I would recommend [this library](https://github.com/digithree/MaterialDateTimePicker), it's very simple, customisable, compatible with many OS versions and looks great.

Answer (score 0):

```
date_of_blood.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
Date value = new Date();
final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(value);
new DatePickerDialog(Raise_Request.this.getContext(), new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int y, int m, int d) {cal.set(1, y);cal.set(2, m);cal.set(5, d);
new TimePickerDialog(Raise_Request.this.getContext(), new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int h, int min) {
cal.set(11, h);
cal.set(12, min);
date_of_blood.setText(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a", Locale.US).format(cal.getTime()));}
}, cal.get(11), cal.get(12), true).show();
}
}, cal.get(1), cal.get(2), cal.get(5)).show();
}
 });
```